# PDO: Quotes in SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm seeing some weirdness when I try to run a query using PDO. The following code shouldn't return results, but it does:

```
$safe_path = $this->_databaseConnection->quote($unsafe_path);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE path=$safe_path LIMIT 1";
$statement_handle = $this->_databaseConnection->query($sql);
var_dump($statement_handle->fetchAll());
```

I'm confused because there aren't single quotes around the `$safe_path` variable as there would be if I were using the mysqli extension - but it's working. If I enclose `$safe_path` in quotes, no results are returned. This seems strange to me.

Comment: Did you `echo $safe_path` after you used `::quote()` function?

Comment: @Michael J.V. I did now! I thought this function was analogous to something like mysqli_real_ecape_string()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already quoting the `$safe_path` variable with your first line in the sample:

```
$safe_path = $this->_databaseConnection->quote($unsafe_path);
```

That is why it works as it stands. If you attempt to add quotes yourself in the:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE path='$safe_path' LIMIT 1";
```

line then you would be doubling up the quotes and therefore breaking the SQL query.

Please see the [manual page for `quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) for more information:

> PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and
>   escapes special characters within the input string, using a quoting
>   style appropriate to the underlying driver.

Comment: I was thinking quote() was the same as mysqli_real_escape_string() - turns out it's not!

Answer (score 2):

The PDO `quote` method just add quotes in a string context.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

> PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required)[...]

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you adding quotes?

```
$safe_path = $this->_databaseConnection->quote($unsafe_path);
```